# use of loops for restarting a process

Tags: c, loops

I am making a battle ship game program which works fines, I am trying to include a loop that informs the player they've already inputted the same coordinate requiring them to type the coordinate again again as well as a loop that notifies them about an invalid coordinate in the shipcoordinate function but each time i do this the program gets stuck on the loop of entering a coordinate in. this is the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void originalboard(int board[][5])
{
int line, column;
for (line = 0; line < 5; line++)
    for (column = 0; column < 5; column++)
   board[line][column] = -1; 
 }
void displboard(int board[][5])
{
//variables declared for storing value in l/c
int line, column;

printf("  __1__  __2__  __3__  __4__  __5__");
printf("\n");
//diff symbols appear based on ship is hit or its miss when new grid generated
for (line = 0; line < 5; line++) {
    printf("%d", line + 1);
    for (column = 0; column < 5; column++) {
        if (board[line][column] == -1) {
            printf("|__~__|");
        }
        else if (board[line][column] == 0) {
            printf("|__*__|");
        }
        else if (board[line][column] == 1) {
            printf("|__X__|");
        }

    }
    printf("\n");
}

}
void Shipsintialize(int ships[][2]) {
srand(time(NULL));
int ship, last;

for (ship = 0; ship < 3; ship++) {
    ships[ship][0] = rand() % 5;
    ships[ship][1] = rand() % 5;

    //check if this shot was not tried
    //if the shot was tried, just get out of the 'do while' loop when draws a pair that was not tried 
    for (last = 0; last < ship; last++) {
        if ((ships[ship][0] == ships[last][0]) && (ships[ship][1] == ships[last][1]))
            do {
                ships[ship][0] = rand() % 5;
                ships[ship][1] = rand() % 5;
            } while ((ships[ship][0] == ships[last][0]) && (ships[ship][1] == ships[last][1]));
    }

}
}

//coordinate values inputted and called from giveshot funct
void shipcoordinate(int shot[2])
{
  //2 arrays used; coordinate require 2 values
while (shot[0] && shot[1] <=5)
{
    printf("Line: ");
    scanf("%d", &shot[0]);
    shot[0]--;

    printf("Column: ");
    scanf("%d", &shot[1]);
    shot[1]--;
}

if (shot[0] && shot[1] >=6)
{
    printf("invalid coordinate");
}

}

int hitship(int shot[2], int ships[][2])
{
int ship;

for (ship = 0; ship < 3; ship++) {
    if (shot[0] == ships[ship][0] && shot[1] == ships[ship][1]) {
        printf("You hit a ship with the shot (%d,%d)\n", shot[0] + 1, shot[1] + 1);
        return 1; //1 returned to give "X" symbol
    }
}
return 0;
}

void tip(int shot[2], int ships[][2], int attempt)
{
int line = 0,
    column = 0,
    row;

//count how many ships there are in line/column
for (row = 0; row < 3; row++) {
    if (ships[row][0] == shot[0])
        line++;
    if (ships[row][1] == shot[1])
        column++;
  }

 printf("\nAttempt %d: \nline %d -> %d ships\ncolumn %d -> %d ships\n",     attempt, shot[0] + 1, line, shot[1] + 1, column);
}

 //condition of board changed here
  void changeBoard(int shot[2], int ships[][2], int board[][5]) {
  //if ship hit symbol "X"
  if (hitship(shot, ships))
    board[shot[0]][shot[1]] = 1;
else
    //if miss or aka 0 "*" is used
    board[shot[0]][shot[1]] = 0;

if (shot[0] && shot[1] >= 6)
{

}
}

int main() {
//initializing parameter of game
int board[5][5];
int ships[3][2];
int shot[2];
int attempts = 0,
    hits = 0;

originalboard(board);
Shipsintialize(ships);

printf("\n");
//do while loop for when 3 ships are hit end game
do {
    displboard(board);
    shipcoordinate(shot);
    attempts++;

    if (hitship(shot, ships)) {
        tip(shot, ships, attempts);
        hits++;
    }
    else
        tip(shot, ships, attempts);

    changeBoard(shot, ships, board);


} while (hits != 3);

printf("\n\n\nFinished game. You were able to hit the three ships in %d attempts\n\n", attempts);
displboard(board);
}
```

Comment: "I'm having a problem" is far too broad.

Comment: The code fragment `if (shot[0] && shot[1] >= 6)
{

}` doesn't do anything useful (because there's no action in the body of the `if` statement).  The first part of the condition only checks whether `shot[0] != 0` — I'm not sure if that's what you intended (it evaluates to true if `shot[0]` is negative, or positive).  I noticed this in `changeBoard()`; there are similar issues in some of the other functions.  If you need to check that both the x and y coordinates are in the range 1..5, then you need a condition like: `if (shot[0] >= 1 && shot[0] <= 5 && shot[1] >= 1 && shot[1] <= 5) { …OK… }`.

Comment: thank you that was helpful it's working